# Looping through API response Node JS

Tags: node.js, node-fetch

I'm trying to pull data from an API and insert it into a MySQL Database. The API has over 100 objects but I can't find any information on how to do this?

I'm using node-fetch to output the Json Data but can't loop through each object? I've added a snippet of the API.

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Device_1"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Device_2"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked it out, should have known now that I look at it, but to help anyone in the future I'll leave the solution.

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

let settings = {
    method: "Get"
};

fetch('http://127.0.0.1:3000/test', settings)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then((json) => {
        for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
            json.id = json[i].id;
            console.log(json.id);
        }
    });
```

Comment: foreach is the recommended method.

Answer (score 2):

let responseFromApi = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Device_1"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Device_2"
  }
];

let insertMany = db.query(
    'INSERT INTO your_table (id, name) VALUES ?',
    [responseFromApi.map(res => [res.id, res.name])],
);

for refrence go through the documentation --> 
https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-nodejs/insert/

You can also use query builders such as KnexJs and others

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you mean, you can use `foreach` to access any of the features of the object, such as the example below.

```
   Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(k){
          console.log(k + ' - ' + obj[k].id);
     });
```